# CORS in Firebase functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The problem is the function is blocked by CORS:

'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I also host a project in Firebase. But it doesn't work either. Blocked by the same error.

My SERVER CODE:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.myfunction = functions.https.onRequest( (req: any, response: any) => { 

  return cors(req, response, () => {

    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); 
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    response.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');  
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); 

    response.status(200).send('hello world');
  });
}
```

My CLIENT CODE:

```
let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
}

this.http.post<any>(URL, {data: 'hello'},config).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);        
});
```

Please help. My head hurts.

Comment: CORS has to be accepted on the Server not the client

Comment: this is the server code

Comment: Does your client have the necessary headers?

Comment: i include the client code in the question now

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of manual response header manipulation but that's what the `cors` middleware is meant to do for you. See the examples here ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps and here ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **Access-Control-Allow-*** headers in your function to match the requests you want to accept.

Here is an **example** of a CORS function written in Node.js from [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) on CORS requests:

```
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

Comment: the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

You need to hard code the URL of the hosting server into the client side.

So in the Angular, you will have service that connects to your backend api endpoint. In here, the 'api url' const must be the URL of the hosting party or hosting server.

Comment: @JhonDoe did hard coding the URL of the hosting server worked?